# Read an XML file java

Tags: java, xml

Hi all I have an XML file in java which holds a 2d array of numbers it looks something like

```
<tableNumbers>
     <row id="0">
         <column id="0"> 4 </column>
         <column id="1"> 2 </column>
         <column id="2"> 5 </column>
         <column id="3"> 6 </column>
    </row>
    <row id="1">
         <column id="0"> 5 </column>
         <column id="1"> 10 </column>
         <column id="2"> 7 </column>
         <column id="3"> 9 </column>
    </row>
</tableNumbers>
```

Now every row in the table has the same number of colums and what I am trying to do is cycle through the xml and store the number from the XML file into an Integer array. (e.g. row 0 column 0 would be stored in numbers[0][0].

The code I currently have is:

```
public static Integer[][] getNumbers(File file, int noRows, int noColums){
        Integer[][] numbersArray = new Integer[noRows][noColumns];

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Document document = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
            Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement(); 

            NodeList rowList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("row");
            if ((rowList != null)) 
                for (int i = 0; i < rowList.getLength(); i++) {
                    NodeList columnsList = rowList.item(i).getChildNodes();
                    if ((columnsList != null)) 
                        for (int j = 0; j < columnsList.getLength(); j++) {
                            Element number = (Element) columnsList.item(j); 
                            System.out.println("(" +i + "," + j + ") " + number.getNodeValue());
                            numbersArray[i][j] = number.getNodeValue();
                        }
                }

            return numbersArray;
        }
        catch (Exception c){}
        return null;
}
```

A few lines from the standard the output are:

```
(0,0) null
(0,1) null
(0,2) null
(0,3) null
(1,0) null
(1,1) null
(1,2) null
(1,3) null
```

The value which is returned from all the cells is `null`. I know the error is reading from the xml file. If anyone could show me where I am going wrong I would be most grateful

Comment: Unrelated comment: you don't need the `&& (rowList.getLength() > 0` and the `&& (columnsList.getLength() > 0)` conditions: if getLength is 0 the loop won't run anyway.

Comment: Thanks modified above to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the following:

```
Element number = (Element) columnsList.item(j);
if ("column".equals(number.getTagName())) }
    System.out.println("(" +i + "," + j + ") " + number.getTextContent());
}
```

Since you may have an empty element. Also, I'm using `getTextContent()` method from `Node` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Is that XML example an accurate copy? If so then your closing 'row' tags have an error. They should be `</row>` (ie. they are missing the slash).

Comment: No I wrote it into the question wrong. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: No worries. I just realised that you wouldn't have gotten the output you have if it didn't recognise the opening and closing tags. Back to the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.println("(" +i + "," + j + ") " + number.item(0).getNodeValue());` instead of `System.out.println("(" +i + "," + j + ") " + number.getNodeValue());`

**OR**

```
NodeList valList = number.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node) valList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
```

Hope that works,

Answer (score 0):

The getNodeValue returns the value of the node - the column nodes don't have a value (except maybe spaces). They should contain text elements though, and they will contain the values you need

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to make it work. Here is the snippet.

```
                    for (int j = 0; j < columnsList.getLength(); j++) {
                        if ("column".equals(columnsList.item(j)
                                .getNodeName())) {
                            Element number = (Element) columnsList.item(j);
                            System.out.println("(" + i + "," + j + ") "
                                    + columnsList.item(j).getTextContent());
                            numbersArray[i][j] = Integer
                                    .parseInt(columnsList.item(j)
                                            .getTextContent().trim());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Let me guess, you used my example and made changes to the code? right?